# state is not updating after reducer reduces

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update my DOM on page load. basically it should show the data of users on render. but it is not happening when I checked through loggers I found that values are not stored in my this.props value. but action was triggered and reducer has done it's task. so my concern so why my mapStatToProps was not update?
 here is my container file

```
import User from "../components/User"
import React from "react"
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {fetchUsers} from "../action/UserAction"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const UserContainer =React.createClass ( { 
    componentWillMount(){
    console.log("componenet will mount")
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers());

},

render(){
console.log(this.props);
    return(
     <User
    name={this.props.users[0].name}
    role={this.props.users[0].role}>
    </User>
    )
}
})

UserContainer.propTypes = {
users:PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    name:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    role:PropTypes.string.isRequired
})).isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps= state => {
    console.log("state",state)
    return{
    users:state.users
    }
}
export  default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(UserContainer)
```

my reducer file

```
export default function reducer(state={users :[]},action){
   // console.log("inside reducer")
   switch(action.type){
       case "FETCH_USERS":{

           const newState={...state,users:action.payload}
           console.log("newSrate",newState)
           return newState
       }
        default: {
  return {
    ...state
  }
        }
}
}
```

and my action file

```
export function fetchUsers(){
    console.log("fetch users")
    return {
        type:"FETCH_USERS",
        payload:"[{'name':'x','roles':'developer'},{'name':'y','role':'god'}]"

    }
}
```

I am getting error like `name is not defined for users` because when I checked this.props users is empty array

Comment: what is your initial state?

Comment: @JoseAPL `state={users : []}`

Comment: I did not defined getIntialState method,if u r asking for users then it is showing as empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your initial state is:

```
state={
  users : []
}
```

and in the first render you are trying to access to `this.props.users[0].name` and `this.props.users[0]` is `undefined` and it will trigger and error.
Update your component like this:

```
import User from "../components/User"
import React from "react"
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {fetchUsers} from "../action/UserAction"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const UserContainer =React.createClass ( { 
    componentWillMount(){
    console.log("componenet will mount")
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers());

},

render(){
    if (!this.props.users.length) return null; // return null if there are no users in the array

    return(
     <User
    name={this.props.users[0].name}
    role={this.props.users[0].role}>
    </User>
    )
}
})

UserContainer.propTypes = {
users:PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    name:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    role:PropTypes.string.isRequired
})).isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps= state => {
    console.log("state",state)
    return{
    users:state.users
    }
}
export  default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(UserContainer)
```

Comment: hey it worked but no it's blank data. how should make wait until I get the data?

Comment: @LowCool instead of `null`, you can render a `<Loading />` component! so the user has feedback of what's going on!

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that your data is loaded properly before you try to show it on the screen. 
If your case is not involving async requests and combine it with redux-think or similar, you can simply try this in your component:

```
if( !users ) {
  return (...loading ...);
}
return (Your content here);
```

Comment: can u please elaborate . I am not making any API call here. mapStatToProps should trigger afer reducer updates the DOM right?

Comment: `users` is an array it will always return `false` if you do `if ( !users )`